# Why does the maximum sum subarray stop working consistently if my int array has more than 65535 elements?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a program that generates an array based on the user input (the array can be descending, ascending and two types of random) and then it calculates the maximum subarray sum using bruteforce, divide and conquer, and dynamic programming. It seems to work fine and dandy up to values of 65535. After that, each sum is different, which shouldn't happen. 35535 is 2 to the power of 16 minus 1, so I was wondering if I'm hitting some limit. When I print the array it seems to print fine, so I don't think that the problem is that the array isn't generating properly.

This is the main class:

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int[] maxsubarray1;
    maxsubarray1 = new Generator(n,args[3]).getArray();
    int[] maxsubarray2 = Arrays.copyOf(maxsubarray1,maxsubarray1.length);
    int[] maxsubarray3 = Arrays.copyOf(maxsubarray1,maxsubarray1.length); 

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(maxsubarray1));
    solver solver = new solver();
    int solution;
    //if (args[5].equalsIgnoreCase("bruteforce")){
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        solution = solver.bruteforce(maxsubarray1, n);
        System.out.println("__________BRUTE FORCE________\nThe sum of the array is "+solution);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        System.out.println(endTime);
    //}
    //if (args[5].equalsIgnoreCase("divideconquer")){
        long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int solutiondivideconquer = solver.divideconquer(maxsubarray2, 0, n);
        System.out.println("__________DIVIDE AND CONQUERE________\nThe sum of the array is "+ solutiondivideconquer);
        long endTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime2;
        System.out.println(endTime2);
    //}
    //if (args[5].equalsIgnoreCase("dynprog")){
        long startTime3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int solutiondynprog = solver.dynprog(maxsubarray3, n);
        System.out.println("__________DYNAMIC PROGRAMMING________\nThe sum of the array is "+ solutiondynprog);
        long endTime3 = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime3;
        System.out.println(endTime3);
    //}
}

}
```

This is the generator code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Generator {

int size;
String type;
int[] generatedArray;

public Generator(int mysize, String mytype){
    size = mysize;
    type = mytype;
    generatedArray = new int[size];
}

public void ascending(){
    for(int i = 0; i < this.size; i++)
        generatedArray[i] = i+1;
}

public void descending(){
    for(int i = this.size -1; i >= 0; i--)
        generatedArray[i] = i+1;
}

public void random(){
    for(int i = 0; i <= this.size -1; i++)
        generatedArray[i] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(-10*this.size, 10*this.size);
}

public void randominter(){
    for(int i = 0; i <= this.size -1; i++)
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            generatedArray[i] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 10*this.size);
        else if (i % 2 == 1)
            generatedArray[i] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(-10*this.size, -1);
}

public int[] getArray(){
    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("descending")){
        this.descending();
        return generatedArray;
    }
    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("ascending")){
        this.ascending();
        return generatedArray;
    }
    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("random")){
        this.random();
        return generatedArray;
    }
    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("randominter")){
        this.randominter();
        return generatedArray;
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

And this is the solver class:

```
public class solver {


//brute force algorithm with complexity O(n^2)
int bruteforce(int array[], int n){

    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    //We go throght all the elements of the list and we try all the
    //posible combinations with all the other elements
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = i; j < n ; j++){
            //we add the an element in the sum
            sum += array[j];
            //we check if the sum with the new element is greater that the value we had before
            if(sum > max){
                //if it's greater, it becomes the new value
                max = sum;
            }
        }    
    }
    //we return the maximum value we have found
    return max;
}

//to implement the divide and conquer algorithm we have to take into account the
// maximum subarray can have elements in the right subarray and in the left subarray
int maxCrossingSum(int array[], int l, int m, int h){
    int sum = 0;
    int left_sum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    //Has the elements on the left part of the arrray
    for ( int i = (int)m; i >= l; i--){
        sum = sum + array[i];
        if( sum > left_sum ){
            left_sum = sum;
        }
    }

    sum = 0;
    int right_sum = 0;
    //Has the elements in the right part of the array
    for ( int j = (int)m+1; j <= h; j++){
        sum = sum + array [j];
        if (sum > right_sum){
            right_sum = sum;
        }
    }
    //returns the sun of the elements on the left and the right of the array
    return left_sum + right_sum; 
}

//returns the sum of the maximum subarray
int maxSubarraySum(int array[], int l, int h){

    if(l == h)
        return array[1];

    int m = (l + h)/2;
    //checks which is the maximum between left and right
    int maxBetweenLeftRight = max(maxSubarraySum(array, l, m), maxSubarraySum(array, m+1,h));
    int crossing = maxCrossingSum(array, l, m,h-1);
    //retrns the maximum between one of the sides and the crossing sum
    return max(maxBetweenLeftRight, crossing);

}
//divide and conquere algorithm with complexity O(nlogn)
 //only made to make it more understandable from the main
//can call maxSubarraySum and it would be the same
int divideconquer (int array[], int l, int h){

    return maxSubarraySum(array, l, h);
}

//dynamic programming algorithm with complexity O(n)
int dynprog(int array[], int n){
    int a = array[0];
    int b = array[0];
    //for all the elements checks if the sum was better until the 
    //step before or adding the element
    for (int i = 1 ; i < n; i++){
        a= max (a+ array[i], array[i]);
        b= max(b, a);
    }
    return b;
}
}
```

Changing all the ints to longs didn't help either.

Comment: it just stops, no error message, stacktrace or anything?

Comment: 65535 is the maximum value of `unsigned short`...

Comment: No, it prints everything, it's just that the sum is inconsistent, when all three sums should be the same no matter what the method is.

Comment: the second if in `if (i % 2 == 0) else if (i % 2 == 1)` is useless because once it entered the else part, `i % 2` will always be 1, so just `else` is enough

Comment: I think you need to work on making this a [mcve]. I suspect that 80% of the code here is not a part of your problem, but the trick is figuring out which 20% *is* relevant. If `Arrays.copyOf` is using a 16-bit value for length somewhere (even due to JIT weirdness or whatever) that sounds like something that ought to be filed as a JVM bug.

Comment: In `Main` class you have `int[]`. In your sorting methods you have `long[]`. This is fatal error, how could you even run that program? What java version are you using?

Comment: @JK _Changing all the ints to longs didn't help either._ I'm guessing they're from different states of rewrite

Comment: @Lance Toth Yes, probably you are right. So then code in question should be changed.

Comment: I think the problem is that the maximum value of the type of variable used to store the value is 65535
try to find another type that stores larger values if it is not long then it must be sth else in c++ you can use unsigned long long int to store values to arround 10^19 so maay be in java there is sth relevalnt

Comment: You are right. Silly me! The code is changed. I am using JDK 1.8.

Comment: The problem is when `n` is larger than 65535, or when values of array are larger than 65535?

Comment: My guess is that you are experiencing integer overflow. And that the limit is not exactly 65535, but just a large enough amount so that the longest sum is larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE. Try changing to long everywhere.

Comment: I guessed overflow aswell, but Java int can hold 2 000 000 000 or more signed, so that can't be, can it?

Comment: @SándorDés What happens when you call all solvers with the same array?

Comment: Well depending on the method for filling the array I use, it will have those values. For example if I choose "ascending" , the array will be filled with values from 1 to N. So if n is 35535, the array will be filled with values from 1 to 35535, increasing one by one.

Comment: @MaxVollmer It is the same array, I duplicate it and they all get an exact copy of the array.

Comment: @SándorDés Yes, that is what is supposed to be the case. Don't trust your code, test it.

Comment: Is it Math.max, which needs to be included, and java.util.*? What are the parameters to start the Program to experience the problem?

Comment: I use java.lang.Integer.max. For example, if I use java -jar "path/to/program.jar" --size 65536 --generator ascending --solver bruteforce

Comment: You need to specify all the informations, needed to run, in the question. All imports, how do I invoke the program, where to look for the error - expected output, experienced output.

Comment: import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom, import java.util.Arrays; It is a program that takes command line arguments. Above there is an example of problematic input. Using the input above, the expected output should be that all methods print 2147516416. The real output is that bruteforce prints 2147483520 and divide and conquer prints 1610596351, and only dynamic programming printed the correct output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've copied your code, changed all ints to longs and it's working fine. Also changed `n = Integer.parseInt(args[0])` instead of `n = Integer.parseInt(args[1])`.
Then I called my program like `program_name 1000 random`.

I've checked in excel, and only bruteforce was wrong. I've changed `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `Long.MIN_VALUE`. And `int sum` to `long sum`.

Main.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        long[] maxsubarray1;
        maxsubarray1 = new Generator(n, args[1]).getArray();
        long[] maxsubarray2 = Arrays.copyOf(maxsubarray1, maxsubarray1.length);
        long[] maxsubarray3 = Arrays.copyOf(maxsubarray1, maxsubarray1.length);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(maxsubarray1));
        solver solver = new solver();
        long solution;
        //if (args[5].equalsIgnoreCase("bruteforce")){
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        solution = solver.bruteforce(maxsubarray1, n);
        System.out.println("__________BRUTE FORCE________\nThe sum of the array is " + solution);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        System.out.println(endTime);
        //}
        //if (args[5].equalsIgnoreCase("divideconquer")){
        long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long solutiondivideconquer = solver.divideconquer(maxsubarray2, 0, n);
        System.out.println("__________DIVIDE AND CONQUERE________\nThe sum of the array is " + solutiondivideconquer);
        long endTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime2;
        System.out.println(endTime2);
        //}
        //if (args[5].equalsIgnoreCase("dynprog")){
        long startTime3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long solutiondynprog = solver.dynprog(maxsubarray3, n);
        System.out.println("__________DYNAMIC PROGRAMMING________\nThe sum of the array is " + solutiondynprog);
        long endTime3 = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime3;
        System.out.println(endTime3);
        //}
    }

}
```

solver.java

```
public class solver {


    //brute force algorithm with complexity O(n^2)
    long bruteforce(long array[], int n){

        long max = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        //We go throght all the elements of the list and we try all the
        //posible combinations with all the other elements
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            long sum = 0;
            for (int j = i; j < n ; j++){
                //we add the an element in the sum
                sum += array[j];
                //we check if the sum with the new element is greater that the value we had before
                if(sum > max){
                    //if it's greater, it becomes the new value
                    max = sum;
                }
            }
        }
        //we return the maximum value we have found
        return max;
    }

    //to implement the divide and conquer algorithm we have to take into account the
// maximum subarray can have elements in the right subarray and in the left subarray
    long maxCrossingSum(long array[], long l, long m, long h){
        long sum = 0;
        long left_sum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        //Has the elements on the left part of the arrray
        for ( int i = (int)m; i >= l; i--){
            sum = sum + array[i];
            if( sum > left_sum ){
                left_sum = sum;
            }
        }

        sum = 0;
        long right_sum = 0;
        //Has the elements in the right part of the array
        for ( int j = (int)m+1; j <= h; j++){
            sum = sum + array [j];
            if (sum > right_sum){
                right_sum = sum;
            }
        }
        //returns the sun of the elements on the left and the right of the array
        return left_sum + right_sum;
    }

    //returns the sum of the maximum subarray
    long maxSubarraySum(long array[], long l, long h){

        if(l == h)
            return array[1];

        long m = (l + h)/2;
        //checks which is the maximum between left and right
        long maxBetweenLeftRight = max(maxSubarraySum(array, l, m), maxSubarraySum(array, m+1,h));
        long crossing = maxCrossingSum(array, l, m,h-1);
        //retrns the maximum between one of the sides and the crossing sum
        return max(maxBetweenLeftRight, crossing);

    }
    //divide and conquere algorithm with complexity O(nlogn)
    //only made to make it more understandable from the main
//can call maxSubarraySum and it would be the same
    long divideconquer (long array[], int l, int h){

        return maxSubarraySum(array, l, h);
    }

    //dynamic programming algorithm with complexity O(n)
    long dynprog(long array[], int n){
        long a = array[0];
        long b = array[0];
        //for all the elements checks if the sum was better until the
        //step before or adding the element
        for (int i = 1 ; i < n; i++){
            a= max (a+ array[i], array[i]);
            b= max(b, a);
        }
        return b;
    }

    private long max(long a, long b) {
        if (a > b ) return a;
        else return b;
    }
}
```

Generator.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Generator {

    int size;
    String type;
    long[] generatedArray;

    public Generator(int mysize, String mytype) {
        size = mysize;
        type = mytype;
        generatedArray = new long[size];
    }

    public void ascending() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.size; i++)
            generatedArray[i] = i + 1;
    }

    public void descending() {
        for (int i = this.size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            generatedArray[i] = i + 1;
    }

    public void random() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= this.size - 1; i++)
            generatedArray[i] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(-10 * this.size, 10 * this.size);
    }

    public void randominter() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= this.size - 1; i++)
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                generatedArray[i] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 10 * this.size);
            else if (i % 2 == 1)
                generatedArray[i] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(-10 * this.size, -1);
    }

    public long[] getArray() {
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("descending")) {
            this.descending();
            return generatedArray;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("ascending")) {
            this.ascending();
            return generatedArray;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("random")) {
            this.random();
            return generatedArray;
        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("randominter")) {
            this.randominter();
            return generatedArray;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing it all to longs and Long.MIN_VALUE did the trick. Apparently, I didn't cast the indexes of the array properly. Thank you! But still, I wonder what could have been the cause? Maybe the sum was too long? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Sándor Dés You had `int sum` instead of `long sum` in brute_force. It was just an integer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong, it CAN BE an overflow error if `Array[i] = i + 1`, since the sum is `length * (min + max) / 2` > Integer.MAX_VALUE